# Error - The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, sharepoint-permissions, custom-permission-level

I use the people picker to select the user that I want to add on intranet (SharePoint Online). I can find the user using People Picker, however, as soon as I click share button to add user in a SharePoint visitors group I get the following message:

An error has occurred in pop up as "The user does not exist or is not unique"

Comment: Have you tried the solutions mentioned?Is there any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This issue could be for many reasons like space in user principal, or user is disabled

please check below solution to solve the problem.

Solution 1: Ensure that there is no space. The most common issue that occurs with the above is inadvertently adding a space character between the elements of the path.

Solution 2: Ensure that the user account is not in a Disabled state in AD.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I will check it.

Comment: Please mark as answer if you are satisfied it will help others